# Как правильнее организовать хранение заявок в базе MySQL

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Подскажите каким образом организовать хранение списка заявок в базе данных?

Одна заявка имеет несколько позиций (картридж,бумага,шкаф, и т.д.). Ей соответствует определенный номер. Каждая организация делает заявки для себя и просматривать может только свои заявки. Нужно, чтобы при просмотре заявок, пользователь, нажав на номер заявки мог просмотреть ее содержимое.

На ум приходит только запись всех позиций заявок от всех организаций в одну таблицу БД с полем "Номер заявки" и при выборе конкретной заявки делать выборку по этому параметру. Есть ли более рациональный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две таблицы:

1. Таблица заявки (id, номер заявки, идентификатор организации, даты оформления, статус)
2. Таблица позиций (id заявки, информация о позиции, количество).